# Code compiles in testing, but errors given when attempting to submit

Tags: html

When attempting to submit code through a custom parser, all script functions cause a return of "Missing  or it's in the wrong place.", "Missing  or it's in the wrong place.", and so on.

When running the code through test compilers, such as JSFiddle, it parses fine.

I am not sure what the issue could be, but the code is as follows:

```
<div class="infobox infobox-limited">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="##B40404">
    <tr>
        <td><b><center><font size="5"><font color="white">Welcome to</font><font color="gold"> Gold's </font><font color="white">Pokémon Battle Association</font></center></b>
            <center><font size="4"><font color="#8A0808"><b>Strength and Honour</b></font>
            </center>
            <center>
                <img src="http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/14/146951/3879604-6282234369-12556.jpg" ;;;;; height="214" width="320">
            </center>
            <center><font size="2"><font color="grey">Read the rules</font>
            </center>
            <center><a href=http://pastebin.com/FeNbG7BC><button>GSPBA Rules</a>
                </button>
            </center>
            <center><a href=http://pastebin.com/r7BhrWVy><button>GSPBA Bracket</a>
                </button>
            </center>
            <center><a href=http://pastebin.com/J6F5G0Ez><button>GSPBA Draft Picks</a>
                </button>
            </center>
            <center>
                <img src='http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/b/b8/059Arcanine.png/250px-059Arcanine.png' height=50 width=50>
                <img src='http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/d/d0/473Mamoswine.png/250px-473Mamoswine.png' height=50 width=50>
                <img src='http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130705021743/olympians/images/1/18/197-Umbreon.png' height=50 width=50>
                <img src='http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/6/65/638Cobalion.png/250px-638Cobalion.png' height=50 width=50>
                <img src='http://veekun.com/dex/media/pokemon/dream-world/645-therian.svg' height=50 width=50>
                <img src='http://pldh.net/media/pokemon/ken_sugimori/update1/479-spin.png' height=50 width=50>
            </center>
            <center><font size="2"><font color="red"><b>PLEASE DO NOT MISS YOUR BATTLES</b></center></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is incomplete HTML.  You start a table and a row, but do not finish either. You have lots of mismatched `<font>` tags.  Basically, there are all sorts of HTML mistakes in here.  You are going to have to learn more HTML basics and probably find a good HTML validator on the web (many free ones) and work until your HTML validates free of errrors.

Comment: So; end with </td></tr></table> before the </div>, and add a </font> after every text that proceeds with <font xxx>, correct?

Comment: That's a start.  Then run it through an HTML validator to see what else pops up.  FYI, in 2015, `<font>` tags are pretty much deprecated in favor of using a class name and CSS style rule to set font, color, etc...  Same with `<center>` and `<b>` tags.

Comment: My biggest issue is that the code I'm working from utilized <font>, <center> etc, but when attempting to submit, I am given an error claiming missing or in the wrong place. I have altered the code using an HTML validater so that the only "error" is doctype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your HTML code here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

There are quite few errors detected by the validator.